# Count(*) filtering on indexed datetime field runs too long

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count all the records created yesterday. There is a *created_at* column and it is indexed.

If i run

```
explain
select count(*) from events where created_at::date = current_date - 1;
```

It says

```
Aggregate  (cost=14365728.05..14365728.06 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Only Scan using index_events_created_at on events  (cost=0.57..14362310.20 rows=1367140 width=0)
        Filter: ((created_at)::date = (('now'::cstring)::date - 1))
```

So it event kind of knows how many rows there are. But the

`select count(*) from events where created_at::date = current_date - 1;`

query itself keeps running forever. Why is that?

Comment: what happens if you use: `select count(*) from events` ?

Comment: "Keeps running forever"... do you mean literally, or just runs longer than you'd like?  If it's running long (but does eventually end), is the result close to the number that appears in the explain plan?

Comment: what type is `created_at` ?

Comment: It took it 10 mins to finish. The actual result was 1,705,401. And the explain plan result was 1,367,140

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza datetime

Comment: There you go. You index a datetime field, but at the moment you cast it as date, optimizer cant use the index.

Comment: Well, that would make sense if the explain plan didn't in fact say that it *is* using the index...

Comment: Dennis do you mean timestamp? There is `date` and also `time` type, but not `datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM events 
WHERE created_at >= current_date - 1
  AND created_at < current_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, to start:  Why is the explain plan able to provide an estimated row count so much quicker than the query can run?

The optimizer is estimating the row count based on stored statistics and/or extrapolations from stored statistics.  As you can see, this isn't necessary very accurate.  (Based on comment discussion, the estimate was off by almost 20%.)  So the query has to actually count, based on either data in the table or data in the index.  So that's more work.  But it's not obvious why it's 10 minutes worth of "more work".

One reasonable guess would be lock contention.  Depending on your transaction isolation settings, it could be that your query keeps having to wait on inserts or updates to the table to finish.  (The optimizer wouldn't have this problem in calculating its estimate, because it will just assume that the effects of concurrent queries are not a big deal for its purposes.)  Even though none of the added data would affect your count, table-level locks could still conflict.

One way to test this theory would be to copy the table, so that you have a table with the same data (and same indexes, etc) that nobody's querying, and see if your count runs faster against it.

(As an aside: In general when the stats seem significantly off you could suspect that the optimizer had picked a poor execution plan; but it's hard to see how an index scan could be the wrong solution here.)